# Is creating instances of a class inside a static PageMethod thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods, pagemethods

I am using jQuery to call PageMethods.  For certain operations, the current user credentials must be validated and for other operations, I need to call other static methods.  Here is some sample code:

Sample #1

```
[WebMethod]
public static void PostComment(string comment)
{
    UserAuth auth = new UserAuth();
    if (auth.isAuthenticated)
        {
            //Post comment here...
        }
}
```

Sample #2

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetComment(int commentId)
{

    commentDto comment = //get comment data from the database...
    string friendlyDate = ConvertFriendlyDate(comment.commentDate);

    return friendlyDate + " " + comment.text;
}

public static string ConvertFriendlyDate(DateTime commentDate)
{
    string friendlyDate = //call static utility method to convert date to friendly format

    return friendlyDate;

}
```

Will I be safe using these kinds of operations?

Am I better to drop page methods and just call a separate ASPX page for my AJAX requests?

Comment: What if I call a common static method from each page method that needs it that processes the user login, will that be thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx

"Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type [Page] are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Therefore as long as your static methods don't touch class-scope objects you should be fine. e.g. this might be bad:

```
static UserAuth auth;
[WebMethod]
public static void PostComment(string comment)
{
    auth = new UserAuth();
    if (auth.isAuthenticated)
        {
            //Post comment here...
        }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha.. so as long as everything is self contained, then I should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you gave look fine.  If you were reusing an instance of an object, then I would make sure that object is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not touching any shared resources, it should be thread safe.

Comment: I have read the text book info, looking for a bit more insight.

Answer (score 0):

see if your class  is immutable that menas no one can change its state if it is changed it will be new instance than you won't need to worry about threading issues but if you are changing some shared state than you should think about synchronization but i don't think you need any thread synchronization in your case.

Comment: I think page methods have to be like this, but I could be wrong